# How to implement a MySQL dump/restore progress bar?

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble using MySQL's built-in progress reporting method for dumping to a file.

According to [this](http://lists.mysql.com/commits/104496), a patch was committed to mysqldump.exe over a year ago that would print progress to the command line every so many lines if mysqldump was invoked with the options --verbose and --show_progress_size. However, when I run the command

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p<password> --verbose --show_progress_size <database_name> > "C:\thingy.sql"
```

I get the error message below:

```
mysqldump: unknown option '--show_progress_size'
```

I am unable to find any record of this option being removed from mysqldump. I am using version 5.1.58 of MySQL community server, with mysqldump at Ver 10.13.

If this feature has indeed been removed, then I am looking for a way to implement an accurate progress bar for dumps and restores.

Answer (score 8):

It seems like version 10.13 of **mysqldump** has been released in 2009 or earlier (to see for yourself, search for "10.13" in [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25162) and have a look at the corresponding MySQL version) and is still being used in the latest version of MySQL.  So the patch probably hasn't been released yet.  It might be worth a try to update to a current version of MySQL, though.

I take it that you're using Windows.  In case I'm wrong and you're on Linux, you could read your dump file using **pv**:

```sh
pv --bytes --eta --progress dump_file | mysql --some-option
```

This will give you some sort of progress bar, although it sometimes lags behind.  Unfortunately, I haven't yet managed to use **pv** during dumping to a file, but maybe this information helps you anyway.